# React Admin - Adding access token to GraphQL request

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, azure-ad-b2c

I am using react-admin and  Azure B2C for authentication, As a data provider I am using react-admin provided graphql, I need to add msal provided accessToken to graphql.
Problem is react-admin initializes dataProvider before authentication, After authentication, I am using below code to re initialize dataProvider. But I need to refresh the page to reinitialize.

I saw some example, where react-admin wrap accessToken around REST request, But not sure how I can implement the same in graphql client.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
const [dataProvider, setDataProvider] = useState(null);
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);
  const [loadedToken, setLoadedToken] = useState(false);

  const account = myMSALObj.getActiveAccount();

  //Calling async method acquireTokenSilent() to get access token, Token expiry and redirection is handled at MSAL.JS lib
  useEffect(() => {
    const acquireToken = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent({
          account,
          ...tokenRequest,
        });
        setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error acquiring access token:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoadedToken(true);
      }
    };
    acquireToken();
  }, [account]);

  // React-Admin method to set data provider
  useEffect(() => {
    buildGraphQLProvider({
      buildQuery: myBuildQuery,
      clientOptions: {
        uri: import.meta.env.VITE_GRAPHQL_URL,
        headers: {
          authMethod: "B2C",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        },
      },
    }).then((graphQlDataProvider) => {
      if (loadedToken) {
        setDataProvider(() => graphQlDataProvider);
      }
    });
  }, [loadedToken,accessToken]);

  if (!dataProvider) {
    return <><CircularProgress /></>;
  }
```

Comment: I think you can use [Apollo Link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/) to dynamically set headers at request time. [This issue](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/4830#issue-620928444) contains an example with `Cookies.get('accessToken')` but the principle should be the same.